# Find specific date in a date array

Tags: arrays, matlab, datetime

I am working with a datetime array `s` constructed as follows:

```matlab
ds = datetime(2010,01,01,'TimeZone','Europe/Berlin');
de = datetime(2030,01,01,'TimeZone','Europe/Berlin');
s = ds:hours(1):de;
```

I am using ismember function to find the first occurrence of a specific date in that array.

```matlab
ind = ismember(s,specificDate); 
startPlace = find(ind,1);
```

The two lines from above are called many times in my application and consume quite some time. It is clear to me that Matlab compares ALL dates from `s` with `specificDate`, even though I need only the first occurrence of specificDate in `s`. So to speed up the application it would be good if Matlab would stop comparing `specificDate` to `s` once the first match is found.

One solution would be to use a while loop, but with the while loop the application becomes even slower (I tried it).

Any idea how to work around this problem?

Comment: `startPlace = find(s == specificDate, 1)` to find the first index where your specific date is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your specific use-case is here, but with the step size between elements of `s` being one hour, your index is simply going to be the difference in hours between your specific date and the start date, plus one. No need to create or search through `s` in the first place:

```
startPlace = hours(specificDate-ds)+1;
```

And an example to test each solution:

```
specificDate = datetime(2017, 1, 1, 'TimeZone', 'Europe/Berlin');  % Sample date

ind = ismember(s, specificDate);  % Compare to the whole vector
startPlace = find(ind, 1);        % Find the index

isequal(startPlace, hours(specificDate-ds)+1)  % Check equality of solutions

ans =

  logical

   1        % Same!
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to save yourself some time is to convert the datetime to a `datenum` in such a case you will be comparing numbers rather than strings, which significantly accelerates your processing time, like this:

```
s_new = datenum(s);
ind = ismember(s_new,datenum(specificDate)); 
startPlace = find(ind,1);
```